# Testing Python "Hello World" in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, lambda

I will apologies first hand if my question formatting is messed up. A noob programmer here

I was following steps defined in the AWS Lambda Developer Guide to run the Hello World code. Ref Page 44

```
def my_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'],
                                    event['last_name'])
    return {
        'message' : message
}
```

Test error in AWS
[image]

I believe my error is that the code is looking for events but the input test event on the test page is providing 3 key values which have no relation to my code.

testpage
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Test Event in the AWS Console provides values that the program expects. It's passing three keys `key1`, `key2`, `key3` while the program expects `first_name` and `last_name`

Just change the Test Event's values to the following instead

```py
{
    "first_name": "foo",
    "last_name": "bar
}
```